# Can't get gas in my truck

Tags: chevrolet, fuel-system, fuel-tank, silverado

I have a 2004 Chevy Silverado. 
When I go to put gas in my truck it stops after like 3 dollars worth of fuel. Since I know it's not full, I click it again and gas shoots back out at me.
What do you guys think my problem is?

Comment: Do you have this problem in any service station? Do you try to fill it after driving for a while? (a faulty fuel gauge could report an empty tank while it's actually full ;-))

Comment: Every service station I went to went to 2 service stations last night  and it did the same thing at each one

Comment: This is a common issue in my part of the world. I think it has something to do with fuel vapor pressure build-up inside the tank that is not properly getting vented. One trick is to pull out the fuel bowser out slightly and try fueling up again. Another trick is to slow down the fuel flow rate

Comment: @Zaid 100% correct that is if there are not physical blockages :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suspect some kind of blockage or restriction in the filler - possibly the hose itself has partially collapsed, or the non-return valve is stuck, stopping the fuel from running down into the tank properly - by the time you got to the second service station, the fuel had worked it's way past the obstruction into the tank, so you could do it again.

Answer (score 1):

My '06 Silverado does something similar, though I don't have any gas which comes back out at me if I try again.

Simply what I do to avoid having the gas filler nozzle not click off on me is to rotate the nozzle about 45° counter-clockwise, so the nozzle and filler hose are at about the 10 to 4 o'clock orientation.

[image]

(**NOTE:** Please forgive my crude PowerPoint representation.)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the canister solenoid vent valve.  This happens due to "topping off" a lot of the times.

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B001KSCSQU/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001KSCSQU)